# What is the valus of this integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals

> what is the value of this integral ?
> $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(\log(x))}{1+x^\pi}\sin(x)\,dx=\text{?}$$

we have $$\cos(\log(x))=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\log(x)^{2n}}{2n!}$$ And from it we find $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(\log(x))}{1+x^{\pi}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(2n)!}\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)^{2n}}{1+x^\pi}\sin(x) \, dx$$  we will arrive at another integration that needs to be calculated more than the first integration.  Please help and give an opinion on this account Even with the added use, the cauchy is useful for the two series $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ .

Comment: Do you have an intuition why you think it should exist in closed form? Will an upper bound do?

Comment: What may be helpful to note is that $$\cos(\log x) = \frac{x^i + x^{-i}}{2} = \operatorname{Re}(x^i)$$ if you want to try to contour this thing.

Comment: A little exercise for anyone who wants to understand typesetting: The title here said $\int_0^\infty \cdots\cdots \sin(x)dx=$?? and when I changed it to $\int_0^\infty \cdots\cdots \sin(x)\,dx={}$??, I not only separated $dx$ from other things with a small space, but I also put curly braces after the "equals" sign". Why that makes it look different, and why the software ought to be designed that way, are your exercises. Hint: This ultimately evolved out of software designed by Donald Knuth, who is smarter than most people.

Comment: $\displaystyle \approx 0.4979$.